# Discord making Ubuntu stutter and internet drops (like in an interval)

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, internet, minecraft

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new SSD I've just bought (Samsung EVO 860 500GB).
I love it a lot, BUT!!!
I have a really frustrating issue! whenever I use Discord, Ubuntu starting to stutter. Like windows are moving at 24fps and like every 3 seconds the whole system freeze for a 0.5-1.0sec.

I've tried to fix the problem using Discord Canary (alpha software) and it did fix the problem only when I'm not in a voice chat! but when I am, the problem persists.
Today I've tried to play Minecraft with my friends and I was using Discord to communicate with them.
As I said above, the problem occurred exactly as I mentioned. But this time with a worse problem, every time there is that "freeze" I would "disconnect" from my network, but not exactly... I'm still connected to the WiFi but the server in the game itself freezes and I can't hear my friends. (Again, for about 0.5-1.0sec...)

I'm dual booting with Windows 10. when that problem happened I've decided to boot into Windows to test if the problem is with my internet (just to check if the problem with my internet is actually my internet) but I've found out that there is no problem on Windows 10 whatsoever. The Internet is working perfectly fine (500Megabits Down & 100Megabits Up).

PLEASE! This is the only issue I've with Ubuntu that made this experience really frustrating!

**Hardware Information:**

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 2070
GPU-Driver: nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary)
Mobo: Gigabyte B450M DS3H
RAM: 16G Of 2x8 Corsair Vengeance 3000mhz
```

> ls -al /var/log/syslog*

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  332960 Jul 25 10:01 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 2211262 Jul 25  2020 /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm  344283 Jul 24 10:02 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 2040148 Jul 23 09:58 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
```

> ls -al /var/log/auth.log*

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 250195 Jul 25 10:01 /var/log/auth.log
```

> tail /var/log/syslog

```
Jul 25 10:01:50 tuvels-linux snapd[933]: 2020/07/25 10:01:50 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
Jul 25 10:02:14 tuvels-linux systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded.
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux anacron[901]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux anacron[6349]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2020-07-25
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux anacron[901]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux anacron[901]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jul 25 10:04:50 tuvels-linux systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Jul 25 10:06:19 tuvels-linux PackageKit: daemon quit
Jul 25 10:06:19 tuvels-linux systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
```

> free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.8Gi        10Gi       210Mi       2.8Gi        12Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

> sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

> dpkg -l *discord*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=========================================
ii  discord-canary 0.0.105      amd64        All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers
```

> grep -i discord /var/log/syslog*

Log was too big (probably because this is a lot of errors or something like that).
So the log is [HERE](https://paste.ee/p/5fccD)

Comment: The snap version of Discord has some real problems. Is that what you're running? Before I go into details, edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/log/syslog*` and `ls -al /var/log/auth.log*` and `tail /var/log/syslog` and lastly `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema I've edited the post but did you mean that I should do it when the problem happens? also, I'm a real newbie so please go easy on me :) Thank you!

Comment: You didn't say if you were running the snap version of Discord. Do `snap list` to find out. Otherwise, do `dpkg -l *discord*`. Please let me know those outputs. Then I'll give you the rundown about Discord :-)

Comment: Also please show me `grep -i discord /var/log/syslog*`. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing vm.swappiness back to 60 and see if that helps. `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60`,

Comment: @heynnema I'm not using the snap version (sorry I forgot to mention), I've edited the post once again and added a link to a HUGE log. I will try to change the swappiness to 60 and get back to you. Thank you :D

Comment: Discord Canary is **alpha** level software, which is bad enough, but as you note, it's bombing syslog. **Alpha** level software should only be run by developers who know how to deal with all of the expected errors. I'd remove Canary and run the normal full release of Discord (if you have to run it at all)... see my next comment...

Comment: In my opinion, Discord has a number of problems, and I consider it spyware. When you run it, it has code to determine what other applications that you're running... and who's business it that? Certainly not Discord or their developers. Also, if you're running the snap version, it requests permissions to do activity outside of its protective sandbox, which should never happen... and then it **REALLY** bombs syslog and auth.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

**Discord and Discord Canary**

Discord Canary is **alpha** level software, which is bad enough, but as you note, it's bombing syslog. **Alpha** level software should only be run by developers who know how to deal with all of the expected errors. I'd remove Discord Canary and run the normal full release of Discord (if you have to run it at all).

In my opinion, Discord has a number of problems, and I consider it spyware. When you run it, it has code to determine what other applications that you're running... and who's business it that? Certainly not Discord or their developers. Also, if you're running the snap version, it requests permissions to do activity outside of its protective sandbox, which should never happen... and then it **REALLY** bombs /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log.

I'd first **immediately** remove Discord Canary, then I'd install the normal "stable" Discord release... not the snap version, but a normal .deb release. See https://discord.com/new/download.

If the "stable" release still has a stuttering problem, try changing vm.swappiness back to 60 and see if that helps... `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=60` (for a temporary change only). If that improves things, to make it permanent...

---

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 16G RAM and 2G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

---

**Update #1:**

To update your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

<strike>Add this line to /etc/fstab...</strike>

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Update #2:**

Updated the Nvidia driver to NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run, and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Output: ```sudo: /home/tuvel/Downloads/Persepolis/Others/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run: command not found``` ; Sorry I don't mean to bother you but I'm a real noob when it comes to that stuff, I hope I'll get better at this.

Comment: @Tokins noob is OK. We all had to start somewhere! Make the file executable with `chmod +x /home/tuvel/Downloads/Persepolis/Others/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run` then `sudo /home/tuvel/Downloads/Persepolis/Others/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.57.run`.

Comment: @Tokins You could also check `Software & Updates` for the same driver.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111031/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-discord-making-ubuntu-stutter-and-internet-drop).